# How to check if an iOS app is running on the simulator. (objective-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime, simulator

Is there a way to check if the app is running on the simulator in Runtime?
I already know how to check at compile time. I want to make sure that the app is running in the simulator at runtime. (not swift, in Objective-C...)
Thank you.

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. Do you mean to check the device locally or some sort of remote monitoring of live users?

Comment: For example, if my app is running on a simulator, I would like to pop up window 'This app is currently running on the simulator'. And if my app is running on an actual iphone deivce, I want to pop up a pop-up stating 'This app is currently running on a real device'. @Seamus

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between checking in compile/runtime because ios devices and simulators have different architectures - `arm64` and `x86_64` accordingly and you can NOT run ARM code on the simulator and vice versa. In other words you have two compiled copies of your code which are build for the target platforms.

To check which one is running you can use the next iOS Simulator SDK flag:

```objectivec
const BOOL IS_SIMULATOR(void) {
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    return YES;
#else
    return NO;
#endif
}
```

Comment: With the release of the mac with the M1 chip, will the output of the arm architecture gradually be able to run in the simulator in the future? @iUrii

Comment: @nickp Maybe there will be some env variables to check but anyway this is a good notice for a separate question.

Comment: this also works on M1 simulator.